# how to change address bar by its content-type/title of node

Tags: nodes, path-aliases

I have a content type where user allowed to add the content, which create a node of that particular content, when i click to that content for detail page it re-direct to the node page created by authenticated user, but the address bar is something like

> www.myexample.com/node/23 23

or some no.
Now i want the address should be

> www.myexample.com/(content-type)/(node-title)

please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Install [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto)
2. Visit the URL Alias Patterns page at /admin/config/search/path/patterns
3. Choose an appropriate token-based pattern for your content type in the relevant text field, before saving. (e.g. `[node:content-type]/[node:title]`)
4. Visit the "Bulk Update" tab and generate all Content aliases.

From now on any time you (or anyone else) creates a node of that type, the URL alias will be automatically set.